# Dynamic Pages Don't Change Rendered Components But URL Changes When Clicking Back Button, Using Link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, next.js

I've been having an issue when creating a blog using Next.js and was hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction as I am relatively new to Next.js.

I'm trying to pull documents from my database on Google Firestore, each one being a different blog post. I am trying to avoid creating individual pages for each blog post and have created a dynamic page, [url].js, that each of the post uses to render.

Anyway my issue comes when I go to a blog post, refresh on that blog post, and then try to hit the back button. The URL will change but the rendered components on the screen do not. So rather than going back to the page with the list of all the blogs, it stays on the current blog post but the url changes to the list of all the blogs.

For example:

If im on *localhost:3000/blog/test-page* then refresh the page and hit back, the url changes to *localhost:3000/blog* but test-page is still showing its contents.

Would anyone be able to help me figure out the best possible way to fix this issue? Thanks

**[url].js**

```
const Post = props => (
  <Layout
          template={"blog"}
  >
      <div className="container">
        <div className="default-content page-styles">   
            <h2 className="title title-small"><span>{props.blogPost.title}</span></h2>             
              {props.blogPost.body.map(block => Components(block))}
        </div>
      </div>
  </Layout>
);
```

**Blog.js**

```
const Blog = (props) => (

<Layout>
   <HeroBanner 
      title={title}
      desktopImage={desktopImage}
      mobileImage={mobileImage}
      mobileImageSmall={mobileImageSmall}
      padding="120px 0px 150px 0px"/>

<section className="default spaced-page">
         <div className="container">
            <div className="default-content" >
               <div className="the-post-section">
               {props.blogPost.map(post => (
                    <div key = {post.id} className="the-post page-styles">
                      <img src={post.image} style={{ height: 180 + "px", width: 310 + "px"}}/>
                      <Link href="/blog/[url]" as={`/blog/${post.url}`}>
                        <h4><a>{post.title}</a></h4>
                      </Link>
                      <div className="clear"></div>
                    </div>
                  ))}
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
</Layout>
);
```

Comment: is there any error in the console, when you hit the back button? it looks like it crashes on the navigation.

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko Unfortunately nothing is thrown when I hit the back button. What makes you think it crashes?

Comment: well, sometimes you may see something like this happens, when it goes wrong you see the state right before that. I noticed you have Blog.js capitalized, is it how it's named in the filesystem? how does your pages dir look like?

Comment: how do you obtain props for your pages? do you have `getInitalProps` for them?

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko it is not capitalized in the file systems. I have getInitalProps which calls the google firestore and collects the blog post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works but not sure if it's the "best practice".

All I had to do was change the Link component from

```
<Link href="/blog/[url]" as={`/blog/${post.url}`}>
    <h4><a>{post.title}</a></h4>
</Link>
```

Remove the *h4* tags and change *href=* into *to=*

```
<Link to="/blog/[url]" as={`/blog/${post.url}`}>
    <a>{post.title}</a>
</Link>
```

Edit: Turns out this actually throws errors in the console, so I may have to find a different way.

Here are the errors.

*Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `href` is marked as required in `Link`, but its value is `undefined`.*

*Link: unknown props found: to*

*Uncaught TypeError: Parameter 'url' must be a string, not undefined*

Comment: href is about what page component to use, so `/blog/[url]` should be ok

Comment: @EvgenyTimoshenko when adding href I get my original issue. It is only when href isn't there that it works but throws errors. Kinda strange.

Comment: Solved! I had to update my dependencies and it worked. Thanks for the help @EvgenyTimoshenko